# How can I have a aws iot rule-engine type of scenario in Azure IoT hub?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-suite

I actually wanted a conditional statement varying an output. For example, if temperature<0 do something, likewise if temperature>50 do something. I wanted to know how is it possible to have this conditional case in Azure Iot? What should i follow? What term should I be looking for? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can query the IoT Hub messages flow in real time using Stream Analytics.  You'll write a SQL like query with your condition (temperature<0) that will then send a message to an output like an Event Hub message queue or write to a database.